# Why does PyCrypto require a C compiler?

Tags: software-installation, compiling, python, cryptography

Is there a python crypto library that does not rely on anything besides python? Or pre-complied bundles of PyCrypto for Linux?

Comment: Most package managers have pycrypto. Or you could use pip to install it.

Comment: using pip returned errors because a C-compiler couldn't be found in my Linux distro -- which I should mention is the adorably portable Levinux

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about non-cryptographic aspects of deploying a piece of software.

Comment: Speed - Crypto.Cipher.ARC4 is at least 2x faster than my rewrite of it in pure python, and we're talking about a ridiculously simple cipher! Security - linking to known good implementations means you can't make typos translating them, and also you're much more likely to avoid side channel attacks in C compared to python :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cryptography involves intensive numerical computations that are significantly faster when implemented in a low-level language such as C and compiled to machine code, than when implemented in a high-level language such as Python and executed as interpreted bytecode. This is why you should expect any library that provides basic cryptographic primitives to be at least partly written in C (or even assembler).

However, Python does include some cryptographic primitives: the [`hashlib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) and [`hmac`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hmac.html) modules provide the most common digest algorithms (MD5, SHA-1, SHA-2) and the corresponding HMAC algorithms.

Furthermore, Python has built-in arbitrary-precision integer arithmetic, which allows efficiently implementing some asymmetric algorithms in pure Python (at least signing and verification, not necessarily key generation). [Python-RSA](http://stuvel.eu/rsa) (`rsa`) is a pure Python implementation of RSA PKCS#1 1.5.

Python does not ship with any encryption algorithms (in particular AES), because the distribution of encryption code is legally restricted in many parts of the world. The [officially recommended](https://docs.python.org/2/library/crypto.html) external library is [PyCrypto](http://www.pycrypto.org/).

You should install PyCrypto. It would be in the standard library if it wasn't for legal restrictions. Most distributions include a Pycrypto package. If yours doesn't (I'm unfamiliar with Levinux), you will need to install gcc. If your distribution lacks gcc (or a cross-compilation system to easily compile packages on a more complete system), it isn't suitable for serious work.

Comment: Thanks, I gave up on Livenux and installed Anaconda on my Mac, which includes a compiled version of PyCrypto! So I'm allllll set now

Comment: "It would be in the standard library if it wasn't for legal restrictions." Just curious, what legal restrictions?

Comment: @twasbrillig Many countries (even democracies) have restrictions on the exportation, importation or distribution of encryption software.